# Determinant of matrix with a column in the form of product of another matrix by a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I am trying to figure a relation for this expression
$$\det B = \det[AV_1,V_2]$$
The matrices $A$ and $B=[AV_1,V_2]$ are $2\times2$, and vectors $V_1$ and $V_2$ are two column vectors. The first column of $B$ is the product of matrix $A$ and vector $V_1$.

Is there a way to write $\det B$ in terms of $\det A$ (or any other identity)?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not what you had in mind but I'll post it anyway:

There is a unique scalar $\delta$ such that
$$\det[Av_1,v_2]+\det[v_1,Av_2]=\delta\cdot\det[v_1,v_2]$$
for all column vectors $v_1,v_2$. This scalar $\delta$ (or sometimes $\delta/2$) is called the *mixed discriminant* of, in this case, $A$ and the identity matrix $I$, written
$$\delta=\mathop{\mathrm{Det}}(A,I)$$
If we write $A=[A_1,A_2]$ and $I=[I_1,I_2]$, then
$$\mathop{\mathrm{Det}}(A,I)=\det[A_1,I_2]+\det[I_1,A_2]$$